# get point on line that the nearest from another point

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 3 points $m(x,y), a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$.
I need to get point $s(x,y)$ that lay between $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$ and this point be the nearest one from $m(x,y)$.
[description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79qUJ.png)

Comment: @zzuussee
check my answer, I use it with big data that why it take alot of process and i'm trying to make it use less process and memory

Comment: I think that a pen and paper approach would benefit you a lot. I don't really know what you code this for, but if you have to, you can most certainly reduce the problem to such a low computational complexity just by drawing the solution and extracting some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

From point $m(x, y)$ draw a perpendicular to the line connecting points $a(x, y)$ and $b(x, y)$. If the intersection point is between these two points then you've got the answer, otherwise pick either $a(x, y)$ or $b(x, y)$ depending on what side of the line segment connecting $a(x, y)$ and $b(x, y)$ the point landed.

Comment: I did this but it take alot of process in my code and i try to find another way.

Comment: the only thing you have to code properly is a perpendicular from a point to a line. this shouldn't take a lot of process, as you say.

Comment: check my answer, I use it with big data that why it take alot of process and i'm trying to make it use less process and memory

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code but i'm trying to make it more fast and use less memory.
 
`function distance_points($a, $b)
{
    return sqrt((($b[0] - $a[0]) * ($b[0] - $a[0])) + (($b[1] - $a[1]) * ($b[1] - $a[1])));
}
function isBetween($a, $b, $c){
$_d_1 = distance_points($a, $c)+distance_points($b, $c);
$_d_2 = distance_points($a, $b);`

```
if(abs($_d_1 -$_d_2) <= 0.00001 ) return true;
else return false;
```

}
function perpendicular_point($a, $b, $p1){
$k = (($b[1]-$a[1]) * ($p1[0]-$a[0]) - ($b[0]-$a[0]) * ($p1[1]-$a[1])) / (pow(($b[1]-$a[1]), 2) + pow(($b[0]-$a[0]), 2));
return array(($p1[0] - $k * ($b[1]-$a[1])), ($p1[1] + $k * ($b[0]-$a[0])));
}
function get_closest_point($a, $b, $p1){
    if(($a[0] == $b[0]) && ($a[1] == $b[1])) return $a;
$p2 = perpendicular_point($a, $b, $p1);
if(isBetween($a, $b, $p2)){
        return $p2;
}
else if(distance_points($p2, $a) > distance_points($p2, $b)){
    return $b;
}
else{
    return $a;
    }
}